# HackRFOne not detected in gnuradio-companion on Fedora

Tags: fedora, gnuradio

I am using Fedora and when I execute `$ hackrf_info` in the terminal, this is displayed:

> Found HackRF board.
>
> Board ID Number: 2 (HackRF One)
>
> Firmware Version: 2014.08.1
>
> Part ID Number: 0xa000cb3c 0x006c4757
>
> Serial Number: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x14d463dc 0x2f908de1

In the log section at the bottom in gnuradio-companion, HackRFOne is not displaying after debugging as an execute device.

Is there a problem with **VID** and **PID** of new versions and old hardware versions — for example statically hard-coded numbers in gnuradio-companion? D

I see this device:

> Bus 002 Device 021: ID 1d50:6089 OpenMoko, Inc.

Where is the problem?

In the source code for GNU-Radio Companion, in which file/files can I edit information for detecting **HackRFOne** hardware?

Comment: GNU Radio does not have a driver for HackRF directly; it's via `gr-osmosdr`. Have you installed gr-osmosdr? Are you using the osmosdr source block? Please post a screenshot of your GRC flowgraph and the text from the log.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's ok, I make upgrade from Fedora 20 to Fedora 21 and it's fine!